# FlipClock с перезагрузкой страницы браузера

Tags: html, jquery, css

**Вопрос:** Как сделать чтобы отсчет был с определенного момента и при перезагрузки страницы браузера не сбрасывался, а продолжал отсчет?

**Использую:** [FlipClock](http://flipclockjs.com/).

**Код:**

```js
var clock;

clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
  //clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
  autoStart: false, //Отключаем автозапуск
  countdown: true,  //Отсчет назад
  language:'ru-ru', //Локаль языка
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {
      $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
    }
  },

});

clock.setTime(60); //Устанавливаем нужное время в секундах
clock.setCountdown(true); //Устанавливаем отсчет назад
clock.start(); //Запускаем отсчет
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>

  <div class="clock"></div>
```

Comment: Придется каждую секунду (или какой там интервал у данной реализации часов) писать в `localStorage` или куки, а при инициализации  считать оттуда значение и начинать с него

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно при первой загрузке устанавливать текущее время в куки или localStorage и проверять, если куки нет, то время 60, если есть, то 60 минус разница между текщим временем и временем в куках

```js
var clock;

clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
  //clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
  autoStart: false, //Отключаем автозапуск
  countdown: true,  //Отсчет назад
  language:'ru-ru', //Локаль языка
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {
      $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
    }
  },

});

if(!$.cookie('time')){
  $.cookie('time', new Date().getTime());
  var time = 60;
}else{
  var time = parseInt(60 - (new Date().getTime() - $.cookie('time'))/1000);
  if(time < 0){
    time = 0;
  }
}

//или то же самое с localStorage
/*
if(!localStorage.getItem("time")){
  localStorage.setItem('time', new Date().getTime());
  var time = 60;
}else{
  var time = parseInt(60 - (new Date().getTime() - localStorage.getItem("time"))/1000);
  if(time < 0){
    time = 0;
  }
}
*/
clock.setTime(time); //Устанавливаем нужное время в секундах
clock.setCountdown(true); //Устанавливаем отсчет назад
clock.start(); //Запускаем отсчет
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

  <div class="clock"></div>
```

Comment: $.cookie is not a function

Comment: @Elena `jquery.cookie` не забыли подключить? - `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js`

Comment: @Elena добавил еще с localStorage

Comment: Спасибо!!! С localStorage заработало!